# Can I cancel a transaction?

Tags: transaction-confirmation, txpool

I sent a transfer but the transaction is still in the transaction pool. Can I cancel it?

Comment: the transaction will be flushed from the mempool after roughly 3 days. you can rebroadcast the transaction again after

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not really. If you didn't include a big enough fee or something it will fall out of the mempool after a day or so, but there's no way to ask all the nodes that have your TX in their mempool to kindly forget about it, afaik.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** Not working from at least *v0.15.0.4*. I am getting the following error:
*"Couldnt send the money: transaction  was rejected by daemon with status: . Reason: double spend".*

**tl;dr:** Reset wallet to make coins spendable again.

Quickest way to free up coins again, is just deleting the wallet .keys file. Then it will force resync, and then the coins are spendable again.

Though you will have two transactions in the mempool, the new transaction will make the older one unusable, once the new one is in a block.

Comment: This is very poor advice to recommend deleting a wallets keys. Depending on the source of the issue, the local tx pool can be flushed and/or the wallet can be made to rescan.